# Unable to keep the input text values on form submit in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a form with Kendo Grid, which grabs the data from a controller. The grid has mostly texts, but the last column is a input text field, with a class of data-role of numerictextbox. What I'm trying to do is to keep the values entered in those fields after the form is submitted and a form validation error(s) is thrown. Is there anyway to do that?

P.S.: I am using ids for that column, but it uses the following syntax #= RowId #_payment, where RowId is a Guid

Below is the partial code from the Grid

```
columns.Bound(c => c.RowId)
                  .Title("Payment")
                  .Width("175px")
                  .Filterable(false)
                  .ClientTemplate("<input type='text' autocomplete='off'  data-Amount-due='#= AmountDue #' class='form-control payment' min='#= MinPayment #' id='#= RowId #_payment' value='' spinners=false required />")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { data_label = "Payment" });
```

I also tried grabbing from JS, but no luck

```
$(".k-input.payment[data-role='numerictextbox']").each(function() {
        var t = $(this).getKendoNumericTextBox();
        var id = t.element.attr("id");
    });
```

Any help is appreciated